# Is there any way to remove a nested class in Python?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

The script below tries to remove the `Inner1` nested class from the class `Outer`. I get the clear error "TypeError: can't delete __class__ attribute". Dead end?

```
def Loader(cls):
    for key in dir(cls):
        value = getattr(cls, key)
        if isinstance(value, type):
            delattr(cls, key)
    return cls

@Loader
class Outer:
    class Inner1:
        X = 1

print(Outer.Inner1.X)
```

Comment: Remember that `__dir__` returns all sorts of things.

Comment: Reducing it to `delattr(Outer, 'Inner1')` will work as expected - what happened was that `dir(cls)` produced the `__class__` attribute, which cannot be deleted from any class as the code produced `delattr(Outer, '__class__')`

Comment: `Loader` tries to remove more than just `Inner1`, it's trying to remove anything inside `cls` that is an instance of `type`. The error is actually really clear - your code tries to remove the `__class__` attribute, it can't.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the following line:

```
if isinstance(value, type):
```

Is matching everything that inherits from `type`. If you wish to only delete that inner classes that are explicitly defined in the decorated class, you could use something like this:

```
from inspect import isclass

def Loader(cls):
    # vars returns the __dict__ attributes, so only names that are explicitely defined in cls.
    for key, value in vars(cls).copy().items():

        # If it is a class, delete it
        if isclass(value):
            delattr(cls, key)

    return cls

@Loader
class Outer:
    class Inner1:
        X = 1

print(Outer.Inner1.X) # AttributeError: type object 'Outer' has no attribute 'Inner1'
```

An alternative, would be to make your decorator a class and tell it specifically the names you want to delete. E.g.

```
class Loader:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # Store the given names to delete
        self.names = args

    def __call__(self, cls):
        for name in self.names:
            try:
                delattr(cls, name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

        return cls

@Loader('Inner1', 'Inner2', 'etc')
class Outer:
    class Inner1:
        X = 1

print(Outer.Inner1.X) # AttributeError: type object 'Outer' has no attribute 'Inner1'
```

That said, I'm not sure why you would decorate a class and define inner classes that you will dynamically delete... why not... just not define them at all? :D

Comment: *"I'm not sure why you would decorate a class and define inner classes that you will dynamically delete... why not... just not define them at all?"* Good question. The only reason I can imagine would be for automated grading of students' work, if I wanted to forbid using a particular feature (like nested classes) for some pedagogical reason. In that case I'd want to know that a nested class was used, rather than delete it, but perhaps deleting the nested class is the right thing to do in some other similarly obscure use-case.